# How do I prevent snowball stemmer in weka from stemming "awful" to "aw"?

Tags: machine-learning, weka, text-mining, text-classification

I am using Weka to classify 2000 IMBD movie reviews. I am following the tutroial on : http://www.stefanoscerra.it/movie-reviews-classification-weka-data-mining/

Whenever I do the stemming, the word "awful" stem to "aw". I've even tried the included LovinsStemmer and got the same result. The tutroial in the page mentioned, still doing the stemming part, but he has "awful" word in the list of attributes.

[image: StringtoWordVector]

[image: attributes]

Also, I am new to Weka, so may be my implementation of the snowball stemmer is incorrect. 
I just downloaded this jar file : http://weka.wikispaces.com/file/view/snowball-20051019.jar/82917267/snowball-20051019.jar

And I set the class path like this: java -classpath “weka.jar: snowball-20051019.jar” weka.gui.GUIChooser

Answer (score 0):

In your dataset, the word "awful" is column 237. To omit it from the filter operation, in Property "attributeIndices", change "first-last" to 1-236,238-last . (untested, off the top of my head)